# gnome-software corrupted and cannot reinstall

Tags: appcenter, thirdpartyapps

I installed few weeks ago gnome-software to use instead of appcenter, because this one didn't work for me - it didn't update any package. Gnome-software did work fine until a couple of days ago, after OS updates it crashed and couldn't find it anymore in my installed apps.

I tried and reinstall it with no success:

```
I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte: 
gnome-software : Dipende: appstream ma non sta per essere installato
E: Impossibile correggere i problemi, ci sono pacchetti danneggiati bloccati.
```

which means that there's a problem with damaged or blocked packages (appstream). But this package is correctly installed:

from /var/lib/dkpg/status

```
Package: appstream
Status: install ok installed
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem: on elementary loki, gnome software 3.20 and appstream 0.10.6 together doesn't work. I had to downgrade appstream to version 0.10.3 to make gnome software working again.